# Lebesgue Integral of a function that vanishes outside the line x=y

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

> Let $ f(x,y)=\begin{cases} xy \ \ if\ \  x=y\\
> 0 \ \ \ \ if\ \ x\neq y\end{cases}$. Compute $ \displaystyle\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y)dxdy $.

---

I know it's strange to write $\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y)dxdy=\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,x)dxdx$.

Here is what I tried. 
Let $g(x)=f(x,x)=x^2$. 
$$
\int_{[0,1]\times [0,1]}f(x,y)dxdy=\int_0^\sqrt{2} g(t)dt$$ (It becomes the integral along the diagonal of the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$). Does it make sense? 
Thank you.

Comment: What is the measure of the domain on which $f\ne 0$?

Comment: $f$ is almost everywhere $0$.

Comment: $f(x,y)=0$ since the line segment $\{(x,x): 0\leqslant x\leqslant 1\}$ is the image of a subset of $\mathbb R^1$ under a Lipschitz continuous map.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wanted to compute it directly :-) But Using the fact that "If $ f=0 $ a.e.  then $\int f =0 $", we  see that the above integral is 0.

Answer (score 1):

By Fubini, this is equal to the double integral over the square; the function is $0$ everywhere except a set of measure $0$, so the integral is $0$.

To see this directly: the inner integral is of a function that is $0$ except at exactly one point, so the inner integral is $0$ for all $y$.